# Latest ServiceStack Swagger-ui NuGet package (v 4.0.30) does not deploy the swagger-ui resource folder

Tags: servicestack, swagger-ui

I have a project that was using the ServiceStack with Swagger-UI, I have installed and setup this up with v4.0.24 and recently upgraded to v4.0.30.

The latest ServiceStack.Api.Swagger NuGet package : https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/  Does not seem to install the /swagger-ui resource folder as the previous package did.

I tried this with a new clean servicestack asp.net solution in VS2013.  Added ServiceStack.Api.Swagger from nuget, and enabled the plugin in AppHost.cs thus :

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    this.AddPlugin(new SwaggerFeature());
}
```

The swagger-ui feature seems to works fine, but it appears the resources (index.html, js, css, etc.) are embedded in the dll, and it is required to edit the index.html at a minumum to configure Swagger-UI.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in the latest NuGet package?

I have edited my swagger v4.0.24 html, css and js, am I safe to pull these from the ServiceStack Git (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger) and manually add / merge them to my solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a good idea to check the [ServiceStack Release Notes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/release-notes.md) to find out what's changed in each release.

Notes for [Swagger changes in v4.0.30](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/release-notes.md#swagger-support):

#### All static resources are now embedded

> All of Swagger's static resources embedded into a single **ServiceStack.Api.Swagger.dll**, taking advantage of the Virtual File Systems [transparent support for Embedded Resources](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Gap#creating-an-embedded-servicestack-app), making it easier to manage and upgrade Swagger as a self-contained unit.

In summary, you no longer need Swagger's assets as they're now embedded in the dll.

## Virtual File System

The docs on the Virtual File System shows how to [override embedded resources](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Virtual-file-system#overriding-embedded-resources-with-static-files):

### Overriding Swaggers Embedded Resources

ServiceStack's [Virtual File System](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Virtual-file-system) supports multiple file source locations where you can override Swagger's embedded files by including your own custom files in the same location as the existing embedded files. This lets you replace built-in ServiceStack embedded resources with your own by simply copying the [/swagger-ui](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/swagger-ui) or [/swagger-ui-bootstrap](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/swagger-ui-bootstrap) files you want to customize and placing them in your Website Directory at the same paths, i.e:

```
/swagger-ui
  /css
  /images
  /lib
  index.html

/swagger-ui-bootstrap
  index.html
  swagger-like-template.html
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, mythz!  So how am I supposed to configure the swagger-ui settings in index.html as I did in the previous version?  

Will the resources embedded in the .dll be overridden if they are present in the /Templates as they are with the servicestack metadata html templates?

Comment: @WinstonWoof See the updated answer. Your static files should still take precedence. You need to put them where they where before i.e. under [/swagger-ui](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/swagger-ui)

Comment: thanks!  Just saw your edit, so does the /swagger-ui resource folder need to be moved to the /tempates folder, or will it take precedence if just in the root of the project as before?

Comment: @WinstonWoof updated again, no `/templates` is not a special folder, it's only for metadata pages. You need to follow the existing folder structure for what you're trying to replace - i.e. it should be in exactly the same `/swagger-ui` location as before.

Comment: Great!  Also I assume that the latest resources can be pulled from : https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger

Does the same apply to the new swagger-ui-bootstrap?

Comment: @WinstonWoof yeah, they're the embedded resources being used for Swagger. Yep, it's the same with all embedded resources, i.e. `/swagger-ui-bootstrap` is no different.